# Dismiss Modal View Controller and Simultaneously Segue from Sending to Different View Controller in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I launch a modal view controller VCM embedded in a Navigation controller from VC1.

The modal VC has a button to go to another View Controller, VC2.

if the user presses the button to go to VC2, I need to simultaneously dismiss the modal and also change the sending from VC1 to VC2. (It's important to dismiss the modal to get rid of it, so I don't have VCs accumulating on the stack.)

Here is the action method in the modal attached to the VC2 button.

```
- (IBAction)VC2ButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
//Above line works fine
    [VC1 performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showVC2" sender:VC1];//No known class method error

}
```

I can dismiss the modal without any problem (first line) but can't figure out how to simultaneously segue to VC2.  There is a storyboard segue in VC1 named 'showVC2' for what it's worth.  I do not have any relevant class methods currently in the sending VC.  Should I create a special class method?  Or how can I invoke a method in the VC that launched the modal.

**Edit:**

I also tried:

```
[self.presentingViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showVC2" sender:self];
```

This compiles but gives runtime error () has no segue with identifier 'showVC2''

I think this is because VC2 is embedded in a tabbarcontroller.

**Edit2:**

I tried putting code in completion handler as suggested by @Oscar but while code gets fired, VC2 does not load

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self gotoVC2];
    }];
```

new method

```
-(void)gotoVC2 {
    LogDebug(@"gotoVC2 called");//DOES log to console
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;

    IDFeedVC *VC2 =
    [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc2"];
    [self presentViewController:VC2 animated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Perform the segue in the completion handler of the dismissViewController call

Comment: What would code be in completion handler?  Segue is from VC1 to VC2.  How do I call method on VC1 from code in VC2?  self.presentingViewController does not grab VC1.  It grabs a tabbar controller that VC1 is embedded in.

Comment: Ah, my bad. You should call `dismiss` from VC1, and present VC2 from the completion handler from the dismiss call in VC1. As you said, presenting it from VC2 won't do anything. To call dismiss from VC1, I suggest creating a delegate for VC2 and conforming VC1 to that delegate. So when you present VC2, you set VC1 as its delegate, VC2 calls out to delegate that it's done and wants to be dismissed, VC1 dismisses it and presents the other modal.